# how to write info section in Marklogic datahub framework plugin

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I would appreciate any hint as how to code MarkLogic DataHub Framework plugins to be able to output the entity "info" section under "instance" (you normally see in entity services).   I think it should be in the content.sjs, but not sure how to write it.     Thanks,

Comment: Please consider reaching out to any MarkLogic employees you have contact with as they'd be happy to walk you through writing code. If you haven't made contact with anyone before, send the consulting group a note: https://www.marklogic.com/product/consulting-services/

Answer (score 1):

You're correct -- `content.sjs` or `content.xqy` (depending on whether you choose to implement with JavaScript or XQuery) will put information into the `instance` section.

For a high-level overview of how the Data Hub Framework works, take a look at the ["How It Works"](https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/understanding/how-it-works/) page. To learn more about the details, I encourage you to follow the [tutorial](https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/tutorial/), particularly the ["Harmonizing the Product Data"](https://marklogic.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/tutorial/harmonizing-product-data/) step.